# Is there a TestNG method similar to ErrorCollector in Junit

Tags: testng

Is there a TestNG method similar to `ErrorCollector` in Junit by which we can display errors/exceptions in `tesng`?

Answer (score 4):

This looks kind of like `SoftAsserts`. `TestNG` has recently introduced soft asserts in 6.8.

```
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;
```

Read more @ http://beust.com/weblog/2012/07/29/reinventing-assertions/